# Component for select friends to invite add my app

Tags: java, facebook, invitation

I'm trying to build component to select friends and send an invitation from my application to them. The following image displays the component provided by Facebook (in this example is another kind of invitation,  but the component is the same).

http://facebook-developer.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/invite-form-output.jpg

I tried to use the site instructions: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form/

But the content is confusing. I need to implement this component in Java and in the case of the site there is a call to the getFacebookUtils () without explanation of what library it belongs in addition to a more concrete explanation.

Need help using this component provided by facebook in Java.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats under the Legacy API and you should not use it for something that is new. Also, to be clear, you cannot send invites, you can only prompt the user to send "invites". What you should use is the Request Dialog (2.0/Frictionless), which is the replacement for "invites". You implement it using javascript on the front end, assuming you are using a web interface.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Comment: Great !I managed to run the example. Additionally, considering the component multi_request_dialog (http://developers.facebook.com/attachment/multi_request_dialog.png/) I wonder if you can have the option to filter through lists (family, restricted or created other lists). Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, the dialog supports specifying a list. But only a list that the user has already created.

Comment: Should anything be done to the list appears in the combobox? I've added a list for testing but it did not appear in the combo.

Comment: You should just be able to leave out the "to" parameter.

Comment: I created a list called "Teste de lista" as the image http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/210/lst1.png/. When I leave out the parameter "to" and open the option of selection friends, it does not display the option to filter the list "Teste de lista" as the image http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/805/lst2.png/.
Following the example of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/
We have two functions:

       sendRequestToOneRecipient and sendRequestToManyRecipients. Calling "ToMany" is already without TO parameter.
Is something wrong?

Comment: I don't think you are doing anything wrong. I just noticed my lists are missing also. They used to be there.